# Revert to an older version of Java

Tags: java, oracle, macos, uninstallation

I need to have Java SE 6 installed on my Mac to run logisim. However, I have a newer version of java installed so logisim won't run. How can I get this newer version off of my Mac so i can download the older one? I have tried the following commands given on the Java/oracle website and am still not having any luck.

```
sudo rm -fr /Library/Internet\ Plug-Ins/JavaAppletPlugin.plugin 
sudo rm -fr /Library/PreferencePanes/JavaControlPanel.prefpane
```

Answer (score 2):

You don't need to uninstall the new java version. You can even use multiple java versions on your mac and switch between them, look at this:

https://www.jenv.be/

Answer (score 0):

No need to uninstall current version of java just follow the below link according to your platform to install older version of java :

windows : http://www.catgovind.com/java/how-to-install-specific-version-of-java-on-your-machine

Linux : https://dev.to/thegroo/install-and-manage-multiple-java-versions-on-linux-using-alternatives-5e93